# GDAL could not initialize class gdalconstConstants

Tags: java, gdal

This is a GDAL issue. Just got the GDAL wrapper successfully working in Java. All goes well so far, opening a file with gdal.Open(), got the georeference data from GetGeoTransform(). In the next lines I'm attempting to load the entire raster into a 2D array, basically the code goes as follows:

```
TheBand = TheFile.GetRasterBand(1);
TheData = new double[extent[0]][extent[1]];
for(int y = 0; y < extent[1]; y++) {
    TheBand.ReadRaster(0, y, extent[0], 1, TheData[y]);
}
```

With extent[] being just the width and height in pixels. However, on the ReadRaster() line I get the following error in the first iteration:

```
Could not initalize class org.gdal.gdal.const.gdalconstConstants
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initalize class org.gdal.gdal.const.gdalconstConstants
    at org.gdal.gdal.Band.ReadRaster(Band.java:139)
    at ....
```